# How to read from servers from .txt file and ping them with C# Application?

Tags: c#, ping

I have Pinger Application written in C# and I want to ping all servers from this .txt file

[servers.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03jfD.png)

Here is my code:

```
 {
     private static void Main(string[] args)
     {
         if (args == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("args");
         Console.WriteLine("Pinger");

         var waiter = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);

         var pingData = new MultiPing(new[] { "google.com","bing.com","stackoverflow.com" }, waiter, 300);

         waiter.Wait();

         Console.WriteLine("Pings:");
         Console.WriteLine(pingData.GetPingInformation());

         Console.WriteLine("Server with lowest ping latency:");
         Console.WriteLine(pingData.GetIp());

         Console.ReadLine();
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `File.ReadAllLines` to read all the text inside a file and loop through the lines.

So, this should solve your problem:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

namespace SO.DtProblem
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        { 
            var servers = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\temp\servers.txt");

            foreach (var line in servers)
            {
                string currentServer = line;
                //Your ping code per currentServer should be here
                //Or do somthing else as you wish

                Console.WriteLine(line);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it is working, but I don't have reputation for upvoting. And don't have enough knowledge for answering questions. Sorry. I will upvote, when will enough reputation